# Recursively search JSON string dictionaries for all values with key value pair in "name"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, recursion

**UPDATE:**

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2xFV/10/

> I accepted one of the below answers although both offered are satisfactory. The one I selected is closer to the direction I myself took. Neither of the offered solutions actually do exactly what I need however.

In practice I ended up writing angular-js function that works for my actual needs and looks like this..

```
function getNames(obj) {
    if(obj.attrs) {
        console.log(obj.attrs.name);
        // expressions that utilize key pair values..
    }
    if(!obj.children) {
        return;
    }
        angular.forEach(obj.children, function(o) {
            getNames(o);
        });
}
```

Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

=========================================

I have a JSON string below and I have to get value of all names. I get that there is a recursive way to do it but I need help. I searched stack for a solution to this but did not find anything that addresses it straight forward.

I am at work. I will update fiddle as soon as I can. My time is quite limited and sometimes I do not get back to my stack stuff immediately. If that is an issue for someone, I apologize. I do not need answers in milliseconds however and I accept constructive criticism :). I will post questions once I have actually managed to get to the fiddle.

```
[
{
    "name": "john",
    "surname": "doe",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "anne",
            "surname": "peters"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "joe",
    "surname": "doe",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "surname": "peters",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "bill",
                    "surname": "peters"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "jim",
    "surname": "doe"
}
]
```

I need to get:

john
anne
joe
bob
bill
jim

Comment: You've done no effort on your fiddle.  You're currently getting a syntax error because of multiple issues with the json string - you needed to use single quotes outside of the whole string, and it helps for it all to be one line, otherwise you have to deal with end-of-line issues.  I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2xFV/2/) that far and added a `JSON.parse` to get it back to a real object, but now you have to do some coding. :-P

Comment: I changed my fiddle twice since that error. I am not getting that any more and I started working on the code. I asked for help with recursive code.. if possible.. if not, no worries,, I will get to it eventually. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function getNames(obj, list) {
  if (!obj) return list;
  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        list = list.concat(getNames(obj[i], []));
    }
    return list;
  }
  if (obj.name) list.push(obj.name);
  if (obj.children) return getNames(obj.children, list);
  return list;
}
// Outputs a list of names
console.log(getNames(JSON.parse(json), []));
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2xFV/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look and adjust to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you should probably demonstrate that you've put in a little bit more effort before asking for help, but after a long break away from code I fancied this as a little warm-up exercise. Something like the following should do it:

```
function getChildren(children) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0, child; i < children.length; i ++) {
        child = children[i]; 
        str += ' ' + child.name;
        if (child.children) {
            str += getChildren(child.children);   
        }
    }
    return str;
}

var names = getChildren(JSON.parse(json));
console.log(names);
```

Thanks to Scott Mermelstein for providing a better fiddle as a starting point. Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2xFV/4/).

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I didn't update my changed fiddle. I don't quite follow what all the fuss is about frankly but I accept it. If people don't want to help they don't have to. I have a 16 hour a day exercise in coding a variety of things and javascript is not my strong side and frankly I neither anticipated quick views nor was I able to concentrate on managing the question fast enough to satisfy someone's sense of urgency. Either way I really do appreciate the help.